# How to make an ideal generated by differential forms into a differential ideal?

Tags: differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Let $M=\mathbb{R}^4$ with standard coordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.

Let $\alpha=x_2dx_1+x_3dx_3+dx_4$ and $\beta=2dx_2+x_1^2dx_3+x_1dx_4$

How to find a 1-form $\gamma$ such that

the ideal generated by $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be a differential ideal?

Here, I think that I need to use the following form of Frobenius theorem:

**Frobenius Theorem** The following are equivalent.

1. An ideal generated by $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_r$ is a differential ideal.
2. The distribution $D=\operatorname{Ker} (\omega_1)\cap\cdots \cap \operatorname{Ker} (\omega_r)$ is involutive.

However, I could not calculate $\operatorname{Ker}\alpha$ and $\operatorname{Ker}\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a $1$-form $\gamma$ so that $d\alpha$, $d\beta$, and $d\gamma$ are all in the ideal generated by $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. So the major **HINT** is: Compute $d\alpha$ and $d\beta$. Can you see an obvious $\gamma$ so that $d\alpha,d\beta\in (\gamma)$?

Comment: Since $d\alpha=-dx_1\wedge dx_2$ and $d\beta=2dx_1\wedge dx_3+dx_1\wedge dx_4$. So, I guess the answer is that $\gamma=dx_1$?

Comment: Sir, then what is the corresponding integral manifold to the differential ideal generated by $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: Your computation of $d\beta$ isn't quite right, but, yes, take $\gamma=dx_1$. The integral manifolds aren't obvious, but the curve passing through the origin has tangent vector $\partial/\partial x_3$.

Comment: $d\beta$ seems $2x_1dx_1\wedge dx_3+dx_1\wedge dx_4$. The following argument correct? Because of dimension, the integral manifold is 1-dimensional, say gen. by a vector field $X$. Then, from $\gamma(X)=0$, we can write $X=f\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} +g\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} +h\frac{\partial}{\partial x_4}$ and $\alpha(X)=0$, $\beta(X)=0$ implies $gx_3+h=0$ and $2f+gx_1^2 +hx_1=0$. So, $h=-gx_3$ and $f=\frac{g(x_1x_3-x_1^2)}{2}$. So, let $g=1$, then the vector field $X=\frac{x_1x_3-x_1^2}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}-x_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_4}$

Comment: Anyway, I really appreciate your helpful comment and answer!

Comment: I haven't thought about how actually explicitly to give the curves, but, yes, up to scalars, there's a unique such $X$ :)