# A closed decomposable non-zero differential form is locally the wedge of coordinate differentials

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$ dimensional manifold, and let $1 \le k < n$. Let $\alpha $ be a closed locally decomposable non-zero $k$-form on $M$.

By decomposable I mean that $\alpha$ be can written (locally) as $\alpha=\alpha_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_k$, where $\alpha_i $ are smooth $1$-forms.

Let $p \in M$. How to prove there exist coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n$ around $p$ such that $\alpha = \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^k$?

---

I am trying to understand first the easier case when we assume the $\alpha_i$ are closed:

Then locally $\alpha_i=df_i$, where the $f_i$ are some smooth functions defined on an open subset $U \subseteq M$. **If** we could complete the $\alpha_i$ to a local frame of closed one-forms $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$, we would have $\alpha_i=df_i$ for every $1 \le i \le n$ would be linearly independent. Thus the map $U \to \mathbb{R}^d$, given by $x \to (f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x))$ would be a local diffeomorphism (by the inverse function theorem, since all the $df_i$ are independent). This means the $f_i$ are the required coordinates.

Comment: Use the inverse function theorem, and the fact that locally a closed $1$-form ca be written as $df$ for $f$ a local smooth function.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your hint. Why can we assume each $\alpha_i$ (in the decomposition) is closed? Or maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: I read too fast I thought you assumed that $\alpha_i$'s to be closed. Let me think about it.

Comment: Do you know Frobenius theorem ?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to use it in this context. I tried looking at the distribution $D=\cap \text{ker} \alpha_i$, but got nowhere.

Comment: Oh, I now see there is an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087199/applying-the-frobenius-theorem-to-a-decomposable-2-form?rq=1